# MongoDB returning arrays using PHP to populate dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

An example of how my collection look like, is as follows -

```
"name" : "input type",
"values" : [
    "ip1",
    "ip2",
    "ip3",
    "ip4",
    "ip5"
]
```

I have a dropdown in my HTML page - The options of which have to be these values - ip1, ip2, etc.

How do i populate them? I tried to do it and keep getting error -

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array
```

My code for this is

```
<?php
          $connection = new MongoClient();

          $db = $connection->universal_data;
          $collection = $db->iptype;

          $cursor = $collection->find();

          $select= '<select name="iptype">';

          foreach($cursor['values'] as $result)
          {
              foreach($result as $val) {
                $select.='<option value="'.$val.'">.$val.</option>';
              }
          }
?>
```

Can someone please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What line is it issuing the error on?

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot The error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array" is for the line "foreach($cursor['values'] as $result)"

Comment: You have to add casting to array before `$collection->find()` like `$cursor = (array) $collection->find();`

Comment: @TomaszW. It now gives "Notice: Undefined index: values" error for the same line. Now that i have converted the $cursor element to an array, how do i access the values element?

Comment: Remove `['values']` so `foreach($cursor as $result)`

Comment: Probably you can also remove casting to (array) - please check it.

Comment: @TomaszW. I am sorry for asking repeatedly. The point is, I dont know how to access the element 'values' in my collection which has 5 different values. Can you please provide me with a way to print that array.

Comment: Did you do what I asked about , which resuls you gain `foreach($cursor as $result) { print_r($result); }`

Comment: @TomaszW. Yes i did what you asked. foreach($cursor as $result) { print_r($result); } results in nothing being displayed on the screen

Comment: It seems to me that this foreach does not iterate over MongoCursor, are you sure there should be any records ?  plese put before foreach `var_dump($cursor->count());`

Comment: @TomaszW.

$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $result) {
    print_r($result[values]);
}

This says - Notice: Use of undefined constant values - assumed 'values'
Array ( [0] => ip1 [1] => ip2 [2] => ip3 [3] => ip4 [4] => ip5 )

Comment: Ok, try this now `foreach($cursor as $result) { foreach($result['values'] as $val) { ... } }

Comment: @TomaszW. That worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to iterate over MongoCursor it is enough to put `$cursor` in `foreach` loop

```
$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    // do something to each document
}
```

In your case you should change your foreach with:

```
foreach ($cursor as $result) {
    foreach ($result['values'] as $val) {
         $select.='<option value="'.$val.'">.$val.</option>';
    }
}
```

Cursor is not an array that's why you have this error.

Comment: The first part of the thing worked. i need to make a drop down and populate it with the array elements. I am not able to figure that out as well. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: I can help you... have you already asked a question on the forum ?

Comment: I am using the select command and trying to populate the options with the values i got, but it is not returning anything

Comment: No i havent asked any question. It was part of my initial question here itself. But the $select= '<select name="iptype">'; and $select.='<option value="'.$val.'">.$val.</option>'; returned nothing

Comment: you should close `select` and return value ... give me a while , I will prepare you the code.

Comment: I also noticed that you have an error in concatenating options in the drop down - in my version it is corrected I mean this part of code `$select.="<option value='" . $val. "'>". $val . "</option>"; ` Here you are @Sid, http://rextester.com/live/ZZA91840

Comment: It is still returning an empty drop down. Can you check if there is anything wrong?

Comment: yes an EMPTY drop-down is displayed. Sorry for the late reply. If you can modify your code and help me further, it would be wonderful